# Subcontracting courses?

Tags: academic-life, academic-freedom

Would it be illegal/ against most university policies to ask a professor if you could teach their classes in exchange for food, shelter, and some access to their brain? A lot of professors don't like teaching or want to get their research done for tenure, so I feel it would be a win-win. It would be a good way to advance myself if i found a professor I wanted to work with.

Comment: Without wanting to sound disparaging, your reasoning made me ROFL :)

Comment: Someone did this at my school (Fullerton College, in southern California) a few years ago, and it caused quite a scandal. The college only found out because a student had missed the final, and when she tried to contact the subcontractor (whom she had only known by first name) through email, the email bounced. It was considered a shameful episode by the administration, and there was concern about possible lawsuits from students.

Comment: @BenCrowell: Interesting, do you know what happened to the faculty member responsible for the course?  I imagine it could lead to firing for dereliction of duty, but I don't know how it would likely play out in practice.

Comment: Food, shelter, and some access to the PI, isn't that what PhD students and postdocs get in exchange for being a TA?

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician: The reason the actual faculty member wanted to subcontract was because he had lined up a better job and wanted to move to another city immediately.

Comment: It is not unusual that individual lectures are taught by TAs or guest lecturers, but the lecturer/professor remains responsible for the course.

Comment: @StrongBad No, I meant in their home. A child I hear can cost $5k a year,thus I would be severely undercutting a TA. This is because I would be using it to prepare for the glorious position of PhD student where I hear some people make upwards of $10k a year to live off of.

Comment: Maybe a related question would be how hard is it to do what Paul Erdos did: exchange shelter and food for raw brain power? How good of a mathematician would I have to be?

Comment: Another related question is how many mathematicians are member of the couchsurfing network. If they admit people into their home then my added value (however little that may be) can only be a plus.

Answer (score 21):

There's no possibility whatsoever that this could work.  To elaborate on Pete L. Clark's answer, here are some reasons:

1. The purpose of a teaching requirement is to have courses taught by the professor, not to have the professor arrange for some random person to teach instead.  The administration and other faculty members would be exceedingly unhappy if they found out this was going on.  Note that there are certain circumstances (called a course buyout) under which grant funding can be used to hire a replacement lecturer so the PI can focus on research, but this can only be done with university approval in advance.  The replacement would be hired through the usual university hiring process.
2. I suppose this depends on the laws in your country, but I can't imagine labor laws permit hiring someone informally in exchange for food, shelter, and conversation.  No university would tolerate this, since the legal risks are enormous.
3. Even if it were legal, it's obviously exploitation.  Universities sometimes exploit people, but I've never heard of any university going so far as this.
4. What if you do a terrible job, or stop showing up, or assign bizarre grades, or harass the students, or try to blackmail the professor?  No university is going to let a random person teach a course without at least some minimal screening or oversight, and no sane professor would accept an unknown stranger's offer to teach their course instead of them.  Even if you just want to be an informal teaching assistant, there's still way too much potential for things to go wrong.

You could offer to give a guest lecture as a volunteer, but I doubt anyone would take you up on that offer unless they knew you well enough to be confident you'd do an acceptable job.  Aside from one-off possibilities like this, you don't have any options outside of the regular process.  You could try to become a graduate teaching assistant or adjunct (depending on your background), but working under the table is not an option.

Comment: To expand upon one possibility mentioned: A designated TA might, on rare occasions, do a lecture or two if the prof is not available (ill/conferene). I've seen this happen only(!) in mathematics and the TA was always the chief TA (the one making up the exercises).

Comment: As a TA I've been asked to do a lecture in a course, because I had better expertise in the topic than the lecturer.  Is that unusual?

Comment: In my (albeit limited) experience it is. Neither in phys nor in math did I ever hear of such a reason. Stand in for an ill/absent prof for one or two lectures: yes, but nothing beyond that.

Answer (score 16):

**Yes**, in all parts of academic culture that I am familiar with, it would be either explicitly illegal (i.e., against the rules of the university) or prohibitively frowned upon for an instructor to subcontract courses in the way you're suggesting.  Bottom line: virtually every faculty member would immediately and thoroughly turn down the request, and those that would not could get themselves in real trouble, up to and including being dismissed from a tenure-track -- or tenured -- position.

One could go into more detail about why this is such a non-starter as well as discuss certain acceptable academic practices which are somewhat related -- e.g. course buyouts, guest lectures, teaching assistants.  Perhaps other answers will explore this.

Comment: :( But some professors are like Dirac, who would stubbornly repeat his lecture notes when asked any question. This would be a good service.

Comment: What about an informal teacher's assistant?

Comment: @123: It doesn't matter whether it would be a good service or not: it is plainly illegal (in any country I'm aware of). You simply can't be an informal teacher in a university. In fact, when you are in a classroom you have a number of legal and safety responsibilities: if an accident happens, then you and the professor who "outsourced" the lessons to you would get into _reaaaaalllll_ trouble.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano: I am currently unable to find any documents that detail "safety and legal responsibilities" of a lecturer in a university, and in fact, your description sounds a lot like what would apply to a schoolteacher with minor students, but hardly so to a university lecturer - there can't be much of a legal duty of supervision towards adult students.

Comment: @O.R. Mapper: I think you are interpreting the comment as a kind of *in loco parentis* -- which I agree does not apply here -- but I don't think that is what is meant.  While there may be few *global* legal or safety requirements, in any particular teaching situation the instructor of record may take on certain additional responsibilities that cannot be passed on to someone else in terms of liability....

Comment: ...For instance, to teach a course you may need access to certain personal information about the students.  In the US this information is strongly protected by "FERPA" restrictions, and instructors receive periodic training and have to pass little online certifications about their knowledge of this.  If a subcontracted instructor gave out all the students' personal information: that could be a legal liability....

Comment: ... Also teaching certain classes involves access to and use of expensive equipment and/or dangerous materials, which may also involve training and certification processes.  If a subcontracted teacher breaks an expensive machine or improperly handles chemicals leading to a student injury: that could be so much worse than if the authorized instructor had done the same thing.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: what if there is a fire or an earthquake? Haven't you the responsibility of ensuring that the students leave the class in an ordered way? What if you are teaching in a lab and a student dies from an electric shock? Are you sure that you cannot be sued for not having enforced safety precautions?

Comment: "what if there is a fire or an earthquake? Haven't you the responsibility of ensuring that the students leave the class in an ordered way?" Given that I have absolutely no training in that regard and little confidence that I could compel the students to do what I told them even if I was suitably calm in such an unusual situation: I'm hoping the answer to that is **no**.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: All right, I agree when it is interpreted to involve such privacy requirements. While there is no privacy-related training for instructors over here, it is probably assumed that everyone who acts as an instructor has at some point signed a contract that involves explicitly confirming to uphold the legally required privacy standards (that are not necessarily specific to education).

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano: In the case of a fire or an earthquake. *someone* (e.g. the appointed fire protection officer) is responsible for ensuring that both the students and the instructors can stay safe (by ensuring signs point to emergency exits, by keeping emergency exits clear of obstacles, by ensuring fire extinguishers are well maintained, etc.). Beyond that, I wouldn't say that there is any further distinction in responsibility; instructors are students are all individuals in danger, and all of them are equally responsible for acting in a way to avoid harm for themselves and the others.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: I agree that the fire example I chose is not appropriate, Pete's examples are more significative.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark *Given that I have absolutely no training in that regard*... really?  No yearly fire drills?  A fire drill clearly counts as training to me, and arguably a class instructor/supervisor has some responsibility to see/verify/report that people are actually leaving?  (They explicitly do have this responsibility where I am)

Comment: @gerrit: "No yearly fire drills?" No yearly fire drills.

Comment: @gerrit: While my university has fire drills, they are just as much drills for instructors (or any other employees) to leave the building as they are to students. And while an instructor can report their *impression* that it *looked like* no-one was left in a room, for lack of any knowledge who was in the room before the alarm, it will be hard to actually testify that everyone left (even more so that everyone arrived at the grouping location, even though that would theoretically indeed be required to happen *somehow*, though not necessarily by involving instructors).

Comment: Maybe we could put further commentary on this point into a new question?  The current question is really not about a deep analysis of fire drills!

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: You mention that it could be a FERPA violation if a subcontractor were to distribute students' grades, which are protected academic data. It seems to me that if this "subcontractor" weren't employed by the university, it would already be a violation for this "subcontractor" to KNOW the students' grades / see their homeworks / read their exams / etc.

Comment: @Tom Church: Yes, certainly.  But maybe in this case no one finds out about it -- see Ben Crowell's comment above.  I was reaching for a worse case scenario...

Answer (score 8):

There are two ways to go about this.

1. Apply to graduate school.
2. Apply for an adjunct faculty position.

Good Luck!

Comment: But I would be doing this to hone my skills, maybe get a publication etc. so that I could then apply to a good Master's program (and know which school had people I like) and then use that to get into a highly ranked PhD program. This would be so I had a decent shot at a research job...

Comment: I think you are going about this the wrong way.  Instead of asking professors to hire you to tutor, you should ask students to hire you to tutor.